# Text file created as log of bash / python not chanigng date

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash, logging

I have a below bash file:

```
python -u '/home/path_to_dir/run_script.py' >> /home/path_to_dir/log_files/run_script.$(date +'%d_%m_%Y').log.txt 2>&1 &
```

The bash file is scheduled to run every time the system starts. Currently, the system is on for 2 days continuously. Today I was looking to open the log files but I see there is only 1 log file for date i.e 06_05_2022.

How can we have the log file for each date while continuously running the script? Also, can we have the date & time before the log? Example:-

> [07-05-2022 13:55:58]  Valid / Error Log

Comment: why not logging from run_script.py and using RotatingFileHandler

Comment: I'd encourage you to use `logrotate`. Then "file.log" is the **current** log, and (depending on your logrotate configuration), "file-2022-05-07.log" is **yesterday's logs

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe the output to a command that writes the output to the log file and add the timestamp to the output. Below is an example implementation.

Don't forget to redirect stderr as well.

```
python -u '/home/path_to_dir/run_script.py' 2>&1 | logging_script &
```

logging_script example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

prefix = '/home/path_to_dir/log_files/run_script'

import time
import sys

last_date = None
logfile = None

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    thetime = time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    if last_date != thetime[:10]:
        last_date = thetime[:10]
        if logfile:
            logfile.close()
        logfilename = f"{prefix}.{last_date.replace('-','_')}.log.txt"
        logfile = open(logfilename, 'a')
    print(f'[{thetime}] {line}', end='', file=logfile)
```